# awk: Summarize a table by first field & combining subsequent columns

Tags: awk

I have the following table:

```
id1 0720f5eb2d611dc66e0e9941d516961f    193 PANTHER PTHR34107       7   187 9.50E-16    T   01.02.19                
id2 32912bc00b9b84f6b06600aff56cef8f    138 PANTHER PTHR10302:SF0       2   119 7.00E-42    T   01.02.19    IPR011344   Single-stranded DNA-binding protein GO:0003697|GO:0006260   Reactome: R-HSA-2151201
id2 32912bc00b9b84f6b06600aff56cef8f    138 PANTHER PTHR10302       2   119 7.00E-42    T   01.02.19    IPR000424   Primosome PriB/single-strand DNA-binding    GO:0003697  Reactome: R-HSA-2151201
```

It is consisting of 16 columns, and is tab-separated.

Now I want to combine this table in the following way:

1. Summarize by the first column
2. Concatenate the columns so that the same fields of each `id` from the original table are separated by `;`

My desired output would therefore be:

```
id2 PTHR10302:SF0; PTHR10302        2-119; 2-119    7.0E-42; 7.0E-42    T; T    IPR011344; IPR000424    Single-stranded DNA-binding protein; Primosome PriB/single-strand DNA-binding
id1     PTHR34107       7-187   9.5E-16 T
```

Column 2, 3, 4 and 10 can be omitted. Column 7 & 8 are combined by `-`.

I could solve `1.` by this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{unique[$1]=(unique[$1] FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 "-" $8 FS $9 FS $10 FS $12 FS $13); next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}'
```

which summarizes by `id`, but does not concatenate the fields:

```
id2     PTHR10302:SF0       2-119   7.0E-42 T   IPR011344   Single-stranded DNA-binding protein PTHR10302       2-119   7.0E-42 T   IPR000424   Primosome PriB/single-strand DNA-binding
id1     PTHR34107       7-187   9.5E-16 T
```

But how do I do `2.`?

Comment: Awk doesn't really adapt elegantly to this because it doesn't support multidimensional arrays.  This would not be very hard to do in e.g. Perl or Python.

Comment: @tripleee, yes, it will not be so elegantly in **awk** as in **Perl/Ruby/Python**, but it's still possible. Look at my answer, please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488587/10306509

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but it's possible.

First, you're need two arrays. One is **'ids'** array and other is **'data'** array.

For each line you should update **'ids'** array (so it will contain all possible ids):

```
  ids[$1] = [$1]
```

Then, in the **'data'** array you should store concatenated data. The indexes of this array will be 'fake'-multidimensional:

```
  data[$1,5] = data[$1,5] ? data[$1,5] "; " $5 : $5
  data[$1,6] = data[$1,6] ? data[$1,6] "; " $6 : $6
  data[$1,78] = data[$1,78] ? data[$1,78] "; " $7 "-" $8 : $7 "-" $8
  data[$1,9] = data[$1,9] ? data[$1,9] "; " $9 : $9
  data[$1,10] = data[$1,10] ? data[$1,10] "; " $10 : $10
  data[$1,12] = data[$1,12] ? data[$1,12] "; " $12 : $12
  data[$1,13] = data[$1,13] ? data[$1,13] "; " $13 : $13
```

In the **'END'** block you should iterate **'ids'** array, but take values from **'data'** array:

```
END {
  for (i in ids)
    print i, data[i,$5], data[i,$6], data[i,$78], data[i,$9], data[i,$10], data[i,$12], data[i,$13]
}
```

P.S.: If you use newer versions of **gawk**, there is easier way to get result, because these versions support true multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As @tripleee mentioned, Perl would do. Check this out

```
$ cat rororo.txt
id1 0720f5eb2d611dc66e0e9941d516961f    193 PANTHER PTHR34107       7   187 9.50E-16    T   01.02.19
id2 32912bc00b9b84f6b06600aff56cef8f    138 PANTHER PTHR10302:SF0       2   119 7.00E-42    T   01.02.19    IPR011344   Single-stranded DNA-binding protein GO:0003697|GO:0006260   Reactome: R-HSA-2151201
id2 32912bc00b9b84f6b06600aff56cef8f    138 PANTHER PTHR10302       2   119 7.00E-42    T   01.02.19    IPR000424   Primosome PriB/single-strand DNA-binding    GO:0003697  Reactome: R-HSA-2151201

$ ./join_tab.pl rororo.txt
id2 PTHR10302:SF0;PTHR10302     2-119;2-119     7.00E-42;7.00E-42       T;T     IPR011344;IPR000424     Single-stranded DNA-binding;Primosome PriB/single-strand
id1 PTHR34107   7-187   9.50E-16        T

$
```

Script:

```
$ cat ./join_tab.pl
perl -lane '
$id=$F[0];
$fs="$F[5]-$F[6]";
$f11="$F[11] $F[12]";
@t4 = @{$kv1{$id}}; push(@t4,$F[4]); $kv1{$id}=[@t4];
@t56 = @{$kv2{$id}}; push(@t56,$fs); $kv2{$id}=[@t56];
@t7 = @{$kv3{$id}}; push(@t7,$F[7]); $kv3{$id}=[@t7];
@t8 = @{$kv4{$id}}; push(@t8,$F[8]); $kv4{$id}=[@t8];
@t10 = @{$kv5{$id}}; push(@t10,$F[10]); $kv5{$id}=[@t10];
@t11 = @{$kv6{$id}}; push(@t11,$f11); $kv6{$id}=[@t11];
END {
while( ($x,$y) = each(%kv1))
{
 @t4=@{$kv1{$x}};  @t56=@{$kv2{$x}};
 @t7 = @{$kv3{$x}};  @t8 = @{$kv4{$x}};
 @t10 = @{$kv5{$x}};  @t11 = @{$kv6{$x}};
 print "$x ", join(";",@t4), "\t",join(";",@t56), "\t",join(";",@t7),"\t",join(";",@t8),"\t",join(";",@t10),"\t",join(";",@t11)   ;
}

} ' $1
$
```

Comment: Yes, but question was about **awk**.

Comment: In **ruby** script to perform this task will look even more beautiful, but the question was still about **awk**.

Comment: ok.. then go for ruby.. if Perl is not an option, then ignore it.. I posted it since @tripleee recommends it and it might help others...tripleee is an expert and his advice is worth..